# Is there a way to stream audio from Windows to macOS with low latency?

Tags: windows, macos, audio, streaming, latency

I'm looking for a way to stream audio from an application or system output device on a Windows system to a mac over my local network. I need it to be high quality and low latency (less than 50 ms).

If I were streaming between two Windows systems I could use VBAN but it doesn't look like anyone makes a VBAN receptor for macOS.

Is there anything else I can use to do this?

Comment: MIDI would be simple... but it's not audio transmission.

Comment: You may want to consider stating the exact results you are aiming for (i.e. what you're specifically trying to accomplish). That is, what are the end results you expect? What (broadly) are you attempting to do with the streamed audio on the Mac?

Comment: @Anaksunaman There's really not too much else to it. I'm just looking to play the audio from Windows on the mac's speakers or one of its other output devices. I want the quality to be high enough that I don't notice any compression artifacts, and for the latency to be less than 50 ms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that VB-Audio's VBAN Receptor works great in macOS using Wine. Combining that with Voicemeeter means I can stream audio from my Windows system to my mac with very little latency.

edit: I've also just learned that there is a native version of VBAN Receptor for sale in the macOS app store that works even better.

Answer (score -1):

Sonobus fits this use case and supports other platforms as well:

https://sonobus.net/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1211831)

Comment: I think this is a great answer to the question, though, since Sonobus does what I was looking for, supports more platforms than VB-Audio, and is a free and open source app, which I generally prefer.